# ¿Por qué me dice error "name 'srt' is not defined"?

Tags: python, python-requests

```
producto = ["Surtido frutas","Cereales" ,"Kilo plateada" ,"Yogurth" ,"Surtido verduras" ,"bebidas" ,"Pack cerveza" ,"Pisco" ,"Hielo","Chocolates","Carbon" ,"Confort" ,"Shampoo" ,"Desodorante","Jabon"]
precio = [3000, 2500, 7990, 250, 3000, 1200, 3800, 3500, 690, 2000, 2250, 4100, 1800, 2250, 1250]

for i in range(len(producto)-1):

    print("codigo: " + srt(i) +", producto: " + producto["surtido frutas,"] + ", Precio: " + precio["3000",])
```

Comment: Es solo un error tipográfico, el builtin/tipo es `str` no `srt`. Debe ser `print("codigo: " + str(i) +", producto: " + producto[i] + ", Precio: " + precio[i])`, pero te recomiendo no concatenar cadenas, es ineficiente, poco estético y legible, usa formato de cadenas: `print(f'codigo: {i}, producto: {producto[i]}, Precio: {precio[i]}')`. Por cierto, bienvenido a [es.so], saludos.

Comment: Ahora me dice que error:  list indices must be intergers or slices, not srt

Comment: Es una buena practica respetar las case. No se si python es Case Sensitive pero ademas tiene una coma estorbandote en el indice producto["surtido frutas,"]

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de salida quieres con ese programa. ¿Puedes poner una muestra de cómo quieres el resultado editando la pregunta?

Comment: Modifiqué mi comentario original al ver se error también, posiblemente lo viste antes de la edición, lógicamente debes usar el índice generado por el `for` y `range` (variable `i`) para indizar sobre las listas. De todas formas se me pasó la conversión a str, en definitiva debe  ser `print("codigo: " + str(i) +", producto: " + producto[i] + ", Precio: " + str(precio[i]))` o `print(f'codigo: {i}, producto: {producto[i]}, Precio: {precio[i]}')`,. Por cierto, `range(len(producto)-1)` te deja fuera el último item, debe ser `range(len(producto))`, el parámetro `stop` no se incluye en el rango.

Comment: Muestre en dos listas, los alimentos disponibles y sus precios respectivos. Crear un código que le permita al usuario, por teclado definir: 1) Cuantos y cuales ítems llevará 2) Que cantidad de ese ítem llevara

Eso es lo que tengo que tengo que  lograr eso gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
producto = ["Surtido frutas","Cereales" ,"Kilo plateada" ,"Yogurth" ,"Surtido 
verduras" ,"bebidas" ,"Pack cerveza" ,"Pisco" ,"Hielo","Chocolates","Carbon" 
,"Confort" ,"Shampoo" ,"Desodorante","Jabon"]
precio = [3000, 2500, 7990, 250, 3000, 1200, 3800, 3500, 690, 2000, 2250, 4100, 1800, 
2250, 1250]

for i in range(len(producto)-1):
    print("codigo: " , i ,", producto: " , producto[i] , ", Precio: " , precio[i])
```

necesitas la "," para concatenar elementos que no sean strings, y usar la i para recorrer las listas que tienes

de todas maneras, poniendo *for i in range(len(producto)-1):* tan solo llegarás hasta el penúltimo elemento, borra el -1 si quieres llegar hasta el final de las listas

Answer (score 0):

Hay un error en la síntaxis, no es srt, sino str()